# Mongodb Time interval query like sql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, express, mongodb-query

My OTP method using postgres SQL

1. Whenever a OTP going to be verified in a table, I delete all rows before 10 minutes. (For OTP valid only for 10 minutes)
2. My SQL query is below-

   ```
   DELETE FROM otp_verification 
   WHERE created_date  < now() - interval '10 minute'
   ```

Now, I want same equivalent query in Mongodb native Nodejs driver using express js

Is it possible without creating index?

Answer (score 1):

well , if you want the MongoDB syntax equivalent to your query that would be :

```
db.otp_verification.deleteMany({"created_date":{$lt: "$currentDate" + 600000}})
```

600,000  is in milisecond = 10 min

Comment: @Deepak what happened here?